# Unable to insert DateTime value to MySQL DB using Java. getting error Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]

Tags: java, mysql, datetime

I am writing code to insert values from CSV files to MySQL DB. one of the SQL columns is DateTime.
I get the value created from CSV and its this: 07/07/10 08:08

```
Timestamp sqlTimestampCreated = Timestamp.valueOf(String.valueOf(created));
statement.setTimestamp(6, sqlTimestampCreated);
```

how to convert 'created' to Datetime and set it to prepared Statement?

Comment: compare the value you get, with the format described in the error message. Can you spot the difference?

Comment: @Stultuske should that matter? code is using `Timestamp` not `String` to set the value into the statement

Comment: Indeed, this sounds like either a driver failure or possibly a "way of configuring the driver" issue.

Comment: maybe it would be helpful to see the the SQL statement! But I must agree with Jon, it is somehow *strange*

Comment: Is it possible that actually the problem is a different field? I agree it would be useful to see the SQL statement and the other values you're using in the insert statement.

Comment: true, this is the 6th argument, we have at least 5 more - please include a [mre] in the question

Comment: Why are you calling `String.valueOf` on what you claim is a piece of text from CSV, and therefore already a `String` object?

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

You said:

> how to convert 'created' to Datetime and set it to prepared Statement?

```java
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 
    … , 
    LocalDateTime.parse( 
        "07/07/10 08:08" , 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uu HH:mm" ) 
    ) 
)
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terribly flawed date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Avoid using `Calendar`, either `Date`, `Timestamp`, `SimpleDateFormat`, etc.

## ISO 8601

I suggest educating the publisher of your data about the virtues in following the ISO 8601 standard for textual representations of date-time values.

The *java.time* classes use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default when parsing/generating text.

The standard format for a date with time but no offset or time zone: YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:MM.

## *java.time*

Parse your input as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) object.

Define a formatting pattern to match your input, using [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.

```
String input = "07/07/10 08:08" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uu HH:mm" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/LauJXu).

> ldt.toString(): 2010-07-07T08:08

Write to your [`DATETIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) column in MySQL.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ldt ) ;
```

Retrieve.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

---

All this has been covered many times on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

Answer (score -2):

Use **SimpleDateFormat** class to format your date object in the required format i.e `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` in your case.

Below is the code to format date using **SimpleDateFormat** class -

```
DateTime yourCsvDate;  //assuming your csv date to be this.
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
simpleDateFormat.format(yourCsvDate);
```

Comment: That format uses minutes twice and a 12-hour format. You can't just copy/paste a format from a server-side error message and expect it to be right for a platform-specific formatting pattern. I'd also *really* hope that there's support for this without explicit string formatting...

Comment: The recommendations by @user16320675 are very good, and I will just add: yes, all of that *is* possible.